# Slow MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, performance, explain

I have a query in MySQL (used in a stored procedure) which searches by name and another field. When I use different combinations of these search parameters, I get quick results (between 1 and 2s) but with some particular values, I get a query which takes 9s to return results on the production website.
The following is what I got out of the EXPLAIN statement:

```
id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key,       key_len, ref,   rows, Extra
--------------------------------------------
1,  SIMPLE,      Names, ref,  IX_Name,       IX_Name,   17,      const, 3173, Using where
```

Name is declared as varchar(40) and the other field is Unsigned smallint(6). I am using an index on the first 15 characters of the Name (IX_Name) which is being used in the query. I can see that the slow queries get a quite large number of rows to check in the "rows" column of the EXPLAIN output.

I am not sure what I can do to improve the performance. Is there anything noticeably wrong with the EXPLAIN output above?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: It might be a good idea to post the slow-executing query.

Comment: Could you show your sql statement? Also, it may be useful to know the cardinality of the names stored in your table.

Answer (score 3):

How did you populate the table?  Indexes are tree structures and to work efficiently they need to be balanced - which will happen automatically if the table is loaded in batch or regular maintenance is applied.  If neither of these is true then the index will be significantly less efficient for those parts of the tree which have grown excessively.

Simplest check is to drop the index and recreate it again.  If you have the same behaviour afterwards it's something else, but at least that's one possibility eliminated.

Comment: Hi Cruachan.

Thanks for your reply. I have a MYISAM 4 million row table and I update it about every week. When I do an update (of about 2000 rows every week), I then perform the following statements:

alter table names order by namenumber desc;
optimize table names;
analyze table names;

but I do not alter the index or recreate it...could that be the problem as you said that the index may be unbalanced? Because that would explain why it only occurs with certain names.

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: It'd be well worth dropping the index and recreating it to try. I've never DBA'd a large MySQL database so I've no direct experience, but certainly this was true of several very large Oracle databases I used to admin. Generally people concentrate on table structure and forget that indexes are storage structures too and should also be managed.

Comment: If you do I'd appreciate it if you posted back the result.

Comment: Thanks. I have 8 indexes on this table. I will drop them all and recreate them when I do an update tomorrow and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your query is only using the index for one field. You mentioned that you search by name and "another field". MySQL (except in very recent version in particular circumstances) is limited to one index per table occurrence in a query. This means that if you have an index on name and and index on the other field, MySQL will likely have to guess at which index would be most helpful and ignore the other one. It seems that a better query structure or index definition would be helpful. If your name is pretty unique and you are getting 3,000 rows in the explain plan, then either the metadata in the DB is not good or you have a ton of other possibilities on the other field.

Can you post the query and the schema for the table?

Are your queries always fast or always slow for the same SQL? i.e. if you search for Fisher sometimes it is fast and sometimes it is slow or are they consistent. If they are consistent, it is probably due to CPU or disk activity. If variable, it is probably due to other queries on the DB.

Also, depending on what you are selecting, if you can get your full result into an index, your query will fly since it will not have to hit the disk to verify the records. I have had pretty amazing improvements with "using index" queries.

Jacob

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you have an index on a prefix. You use the first 15 characters, but let's pretend you used only 1, and your table had these values for names:

Al
Barb
Beth
Betsy
Bill
Biff
Bob
Bonny
Buck
Bud
Carl

Since my index is only on the first character, the database has to get read all the rows the index gives back, and compare each entire name to the predicate.

Now, if I look for 'Al', my index gives one row back. I then compare 'Al' in the preicate to 'Al' in the row, and I have a match, so I return that row, and I'm done.

Now if I look for 'Alex', my index gives one row back. I then compare 'Alex' in the preicate to 'Al' in the row, and I have no match, and no more potential matches, and I'm done.

But if I look for 'Bud' (or anything beginning with 'B'), my index gives nine rows back. I have nine rows I need to read, and compare to the predicate, before I'm done.

Do this:

```
select substring( name, 1, 15), count(*)
from names
group by substring( name, 1, 15);
```

I think you'll find your quick lookups have are unique, while the slow ones are where many names share a common prefix.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...The thing is, I am looking for the complete name (Fischer) so in this case I do not think the prefix is an issue as it is less than 15 chars anyway...And I think the names are nearly unique after 15 characters.
Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

I find 3173 rows to consider a fairly large number, assuming you want to render them to a user. If the actual number of records retrieved is substantially smaller, you should consider creating more indices. It would be useful to know what EXPLAIN reports for a different search term.